# Displaying a join using three models in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Basically the functionality of the site allows users to follow other users, and they also receive a feed of the sightings that users they are following have made. These sightings are sent from the mobile app.

Everything works as expected except, when I look at a user's profile page (the SHOW action) all the sightings are displayed, including sightings not made by that user. I'm sure it's something to do with a join I'm making in the `users_controller`.

Here's the SHOW action:

```
def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @sightings = @user.sightings.paginate(page: params[:page], :per_page => 20)
    @birds = Bird.joins(:sightings)
end
```

Here's the view that calls it:

```
<% if @user.sightings.any? %>
      <ul class="list">
          <% @birds.each do |bird| %>
          <%= render bird %>
          <% end %>       
      </ul>
      <%= will_paginate @sightings %>
<% end %>
```

I'm obviously missing something fundamental with the join but it looks to me like it should work with the code I have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your third line `@birds = Bird.joins(:sightings)` you're joining all sightings to all birds. Try the following instead:

```
@birds = Bird.joins(:sightings).where("sightings.user_id = ?", @user.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

I might be guessing, but you probably have `Sighting#belongs_to :bird` association. If it's the case I would prefer:

```
@birds = @users.sightings.map(&:bird)
```

Comment: No I have a standard 'Bird has_many :sightings' and 'Sighting belongs_to :bird'association. In any case, thanks for showing me a new way to map relations, I'm sure it will be useful...